# How to restore/create linked server logins from one server to another

Tags: sql-server

Here is the situation I am in. I have backup files for databases that I am using to restore them on a test server(B). The issue that I am having is that linked server logins appear to be on the master server level and I am unable to use those through a database's backup file.

I create these backup files from another server(A) and store them in a remote location. Is there a way to create a file or something with all the linked server logins from server A and use that file to restore them somehow when I use backup files to create Databases on Server B?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the site. Why can't you just script the linked server and the logins and execute it after the restore? Is there any problem with that I'm missing?

Comment: @TomV Thank you for the reply. I could definitely do that. But I want the script to reside in a remote file storage. Reason: I don't want server B(does not contain logins) to depend on Server A(has the login info) every time I restore each database from backup files. Let me know if I can explain better.

Comment: yes I don't understand what you mean by that comment. What problem are you trying to avoid?

Comment: This is the situation:
1. I have a job that creates backup files for each DataBase on server A and dumps into remote file storage.
2. I have another job that utilizes these backup files to create Databases on the specified server B. And that could be Sql server running on a docker container too.
3. In job 1 if I could somehow generate a script that has all the linked server logins etc and dump that too in the file storage, I would be able to use that file in job 2. Is there a good way that you can suggest to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Copy-DbaLinkedServer`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Copy-DbaLinkedServer) from dbatools to migrate linked servers.

For login migration, you can use [copy-dbalogin](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Copy-DbaLogin)

Just install [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/download/) and you will get all the cmdlets.

Also, see my answer if you want to [dump the scripted output into file.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/220271/8783)

Comment: Thank you for that tip. Is there a way that I could do this without dbatools? Like dump all the info to a file and then use that file in code and execute a command?

Comment: You have to build your own. But why reinvent the wheel when you have a solution that does it for you ? dbatools has an option to dump the generated code into file as well.